# IntelliSense in Visual Studio Code not working properly

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I have installed VS Code to my Arch Linux laptop to write C# programs instead of Visual Studio on Windows.
I have installed C# and .NET extensions, but I have no normal code suggestions for types, libraries, etc.

It suggests only language operators as if/else/using etc.

I tried reinstalling, and installing different versions of these extensions, but to no avail.
Also I tried to turn on IntelliSense in Settings, but it was turned on by default.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Go to your extensions marketplace, and disable everything pertaining to C#, like the .NET Runtime Install Tool, C# Dev Kit, IntelliCode for C# Dev Kit, C#.

After this, VS Code will ask you to reload.

Then, after the reload, enable it back. It will ask to restart language server. Click OK, then go to your Program.cs file, and type literally anything, and wait for a few seconds.

Although, this is a quick fix. You'll have to redo this anytime you face the issue. I'm still looking for a permanent fix. You can also revert the version of your C# base extensions to version 1.#.

I hope this helps. Also check [this reply](https://github.com/dotnet/vscode-csharp/issues/5742#issuecomment-1668651076) on a related GitHub issue.

Comment: Hi! Your recomendation in pair with installing 3 month and older versios of that packages helped me. Tysm

Comment: nothing in the question post suggests that the asker is doing remote development...

Comment: @starball i know but there are some helpful answers there that seems to help